# Create new rows with group by columns for missing days

Tags: python

I did many searches but could not find a solution to this simple problem.

I have a dataframe with many columns, for simplicity, I only show 4 columns like this one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'groups': ['A', 'A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
   'date': [6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535, 6535],
   'days': [1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14],
   'price': [64, 82, 31, 77, 21, 39, 79, 67, 45, 66, 24, 60, 64, 56, 41, 29, 60, 57, 68]
})
```

I want to create new rows for missing days so that I get a table like this one

[image]

So I want to group by `groups` and `date`, then scan through the `days` column (with a range of 1 to 15) and add a row for missing days that copies rows of `groups` and `date` based on the group by but the `price` column will have a value of NaN (empty cell).

I look for a similar solution to this one in R

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(date,groups) %>% complete(days = 1:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this to solve the question. It is a bit messy compared to the easy solution in R. Hopefully someone else can have better and nicer codes

```
def reindex(df):
    min_ = 1
    max_ = 16
    index = range(min_, max_)
    df.set_index('days', inplace = True)
    df_reindexed = df.reindex(index).reset_index()
    cols = list(set(df.columns) - set(['price']))
    df_reindexed[cols] = df_reindexed[cols].ffill().bfill()
    return df_reindexed

df2 = df1.groupby(['groups', 'date'], as_index=False).apply(reindex)
df2
```